# Can I summon this mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

> /summon Slime ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:0,Size:2,CustomName:Spikes,CustomNameVisible:0,Attributes:[{Name:generic.attackDamage,Base:30.0},],ActiveEffects:[{Ambient:1,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999999,Id:},],Riding:{id:Skeleton,Invulnerable:0,CustomName:Dinnerbone,CustomNameVisible:0,ActiveEffects:[{Ambient:1,Amplifier:128,Duration:999999999,Id:8}],Equipment:[{id:,Count:,Damage:},{id:,Count:,Damage:},{id:,Count:,Damage:},{id:,Count:,Damage:},{id:,Count:,Damage:}],}}

I'm using 1.12.2.

Can I summon this mob and if no how can I make it work?

Comment: You gave no indication what you want the command to do. What do you expext as an answer? "Yes, you can write this into a command block and activate it"? Checking if the syntax is correct, which you could simply do by trying it? Comparing it with your goal that we don't know?

Answer (score 1):

You can not summon that mob.  That command has a lot of problems.  Arguments with no values, commas with no purpose, use of the [Riding tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags#Entities) which was replaced in 1.9 with Passengers tag, specifying [tilde notation](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Tilde_and_Caret_notation) with 0's.

The skeleton's equipment section contains no values at all.

Here is an equivalent command that does work:

```
summon skeleton ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:0,CustomName:Dinnerbone,CustomNameVisible:0,ActiveEffects:[{Ambient:1,Amplifier:128,Duration:999999999,Id:8}],Passengers:[{id:Slime,Invulnerable:0,Size:2,CustomName:Spikes,CustomNameVisible:0,Attributes:[{Name:generic.attackDamage,Base:30.0}],ActiveEffects:[{Ambient:1,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999999,Id:8}]}]}
```

Here is a picture  of the results:
[image: Little Guy]

---

Edit to include requested information in the comment.  Here is the mob with an invisible slime and a skeleton who doesn't move:

```
summon skeleton ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:0,CustomName:Dinnerbone,CustomNameVisible:0,Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0}],Passengers:[{id:Slime,Invulnerable:0,Size:2,CustomName:Spikes,CustomNameVisible:0,Attributes:[{Name:generic.attackDamage,Base:30.0}],ActiveEffects:[{Ambient:1,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999999,Id:14}]}]}
```

**Note**: Decreasing speed of skeleton uses an attribute instead of an effect as there is a bug which prevents the slowness effect from working on mobs through summon command.  The bug report: [MC-32575](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-32575) if you are interested.

Comment: How do I make the slime invisible and give the skeleton an infinite slowness effect?

Comment: Why bother with the slime if it is invisible?  What is your end goal?  What are you trying to summon?  An upside down skeleton with slowness?